# Java Spring Security exception

Tags: java, exception, spring-security

I get exception `No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`, when start web app, but not understand why. My configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Inject private TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    @Inject private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Inject private DefaultEntryPoint defaultEntryPoint;
    @Inject
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    private XAuthTokenConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new XAuthTokenConfigurer(userDetailsService, tokenProvider);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(defaultEntryPoint)
        .and()
                .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter())
        .and()
              .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/feed").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    @Bean
    public TokenProvider tokenProvider(){
        String secret = "secret";
        int validityInSeconds = 172800;
        return new TokenProvider(secret, validityInSeconds, 172800);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico")
                .antMatchers("/resources/**")
                .antMatchers("/userresources/**");
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

This security initializer configurations:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityInit extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

And application initializer:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
        ctx.register(DatabaseConfig.class);
        ctx.register(SecurityConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

In my application I have defined this is web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And I have the spring-web jar in the classpath.